# Reload a listview through fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am relatively new to using fragments and having difficulty figuring out how to reload my list view that was initialized in a `BaseFragment` while I'm in a `FragmentActivity` I am using the Universal image loader with a `listview` and have it working correctly in my project, I just need to figure out how to reload it with out reloading the whole activity.

here is my **Basefragment** where i believe the `listview` is first initialized:

```
public class ImageListFragment extends AbsListViewBaseFragment {

    public static final int INDEX = 0;
    String[] imageUrls = Constants2photo.IMAGES.toArray(new String[Constants2photo.IMAGES.size()]);

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_image_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lister);
        ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImagePagerActivity(position);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
...
```

And here is my **fragment activity** onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int frIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants2photo.Extra.FRAGMENT_INDEX, 0);
    Fragment fr;
    String tag;
    int titleRes;
    switch (frIndex) {
        default:
        case ImageListFragment.INDEX:
            tag = ImageListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (fr == null) {
                fr = new ImageListFragment();
            }
            titleRes = R.string.ac_name_image_list;
            break;
        case ImagePagerFragment.INDEX:
            tag = ImagePagerFragment.class.getSimpleName();
            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (fr == null) {
                fr = new ImagePagerFragment();
                fr.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            }
            titleRes = R.string.ac_name_image_pager;
            break;

    }

    setTitle(titleRes);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fr, tag).commit();
}
```

**EDIT**

**Image adapter class:**

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    ImageAdapter() {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_image, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.image, options, animateFirstListener);

        return view;
    }
}
```

So how do I reload the listview from the fragment activity? let me know if I need to post more code, really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this in your fragment

**NOTE** Seems you are using samples from universal image loader (nostra). In sample they are using `AbsListView` whose `getAdapter` method returns a `ListAdapter` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not part of it. That's why you need to cast your adapter to `BaseAdapter`

```
public void refresh()
{
    ((BaseAdapter)this.listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and to refresh do this in your activity

```
Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
if(fr instanceOf ImageListFragment)
    ((ImageListFragment)fr).refresh();
```

Comment: I get `cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged()` in the base fragment

Comment: What class your `ImageAdapter` class is extending?

Comment: Ok that worked for the first part, now in my fragment activity I get cannot resolve refresh

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageListFragment` you could create a method such as :

```
public void updateList(){
  this.ListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
  ...other stuff you wanna do to refresh your list....
```

}

And then in your activity you could refresh your list in your fragment whenever you want to by:

```
fr = new ImageListFragment();

...

fr.updateList();
```

Comment: I get `cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged()` in the base fragment